# Regarding Connecting Two Java Programs

Tags: java, pipeline

So I'm trying to practice connecting out of one java program to the input of another program and I'm wondering if the way I did it is efficient or if there's a better way. I'm saving a string into a text file in the first program and reading the string then printing it out in the second. Is there a way to just cut out using the text file as a middle man?

Here's my first program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class pip1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String inString = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        inString = sc.next();
        try{
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("word.txt");
            out.println(inString);
            out.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){ }
    }
}
```

and here is the second:

```
import java.io.*;

public class pip2{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "word.txt";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String outString = br.readLine();
            br.close();
            fr.close();

            System.out.println(outString);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}
          catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just write to stdout in the first one, read from stdin in your second, and just pipe the output of the first into the second when you run in: `java pip1 | java pip2`.

Comment: Andy's way is easy and perfect if you use *nix.

Comment: It worked in [windows XP too](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) - have MS removed it?

Comment: Whoops.. I have checked and it indeed works in Windows... Sorry that I didn't know it..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is a pipe, which acts as a "intermediate wire" between two processes without using an "temporary file".

So I recommend you to read doc about Pipes in JAVA.

Here's [a link of tutorial.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html)

Also see [javadoc about PipedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html)

[javadoc about PipedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html)

What's more, if your OS supports IO redirection from terminal, then just do it without using , as Andy says. This would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Just write to `System.out` in the first one, read from `System.in` in your second, and use a pipe to connect the output of the first into the second when you run the two commands:

```
java pip1 | java pip2
```